# initdb: error: program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was not found using circleci ubuntu docker-compose docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, docker-compose, circleci, postgresql-initdb

I am using docker-compose on circleci to spin up a postgres container with a bunch of sql files mounted on `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. I am using an ubuntu machine image: `ubuntu-2004:202010-01`, but I am getting the error:

```
popen failure: Cannot allocate memory
initdb: error: program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was not found in the same directory as "/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin/initdb"
```

This has always been woking, but at some point it stopped doing so. Any suggestion on what I can try? I already tried with some bigger `resource_type` (ie from medium to large) and some other ubuntu machine images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All versions, including the latest one, are encountering this issue. I was stuck for nearly a day when I attempted to use this image `15-bullseye` that solves the problem.

This is the github open issue I got the solution:
https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/1099#issuecomment-1593228770

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working with a different machine image

```
    machine:
      image: ubuntu-2004:2023.04.2
```

This might be useful link to check available images: https://circleci.com/developer/machine/image/ubuntu-2004

Comment: Same here, changed image postgres to postgres:15.3-bullseye and problem solved

Comment: @TechGeorgii The `15.3-bullseye` version resolved my error, thank you.